# android.support.v4.view.ViewPager not working on API 26 (Oreo)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager to make an image slider and it works perfectly on API 22, but when I run the same code on API 26, `findViewById` returns `null`.

My gradle app config:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}}
```

I use support library version `27.1.1`.

Why the ViewPager does not initialize at API 26? :(

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager imagePager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    imagePager = findViewById(R.id.forklift_view_pager);
    configureToolbar();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void configureToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.detail_activity_toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_forklift_logo_transp_white_toolbar_size);
        Drawable backArrow = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
        if (backArrow != null) {
            backArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
    }
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_layout_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/forklift_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />
```

Comment: Please show how you initialize your ViewPager

Comment: @H.Brooks please see the updated post. thanks

Comment: And how did you import it?

Comment: @H.Brooks import what?

Comment: Your `ViewPager`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I was just not paying attention and I had two layout files (one for v26 - I do not remember how it was created) for the same activity. Thus I was updating the `id` values in only one of these XML files.